# 'I am alone' vs 'I am lonely'

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between the following?

> I am lonely
>
> I am alone

'Lonely' and 'alone' both are adjectives and adverbs, that is why I am confused.

Comment: I think saying *"I'm feeling alone,"* is not much different in meaning from saying *"I'm feeling lonely."* The difference would become clearer when you compare *"I'm alone,"* with *"I'm lonely."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am alone means I am by myself; there is no one else around.

> [alone](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alone) 1. Being apart from others; solitary.

I am lonely means that I feel sad because I don't have anyone else around me- I miss the presence of other people.

> [lonely](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lonely) a. Dejected by the awareness of being alone

You can be lonely when you are alone or you can be alone without feeling the least bit lonely.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm Alone* means, Your are alone, I have no one else hear near me.

*I'm Lonely* means I'm alone I have no one by my side at the moment, I want someone's presence near me.

I'm Lonely and I'm Alone mean two different things, but they do have somewhat similar meanings. But that doesn't mean they have the same meaning.